# How to check if dataframe columns contains any information except NULL/EMPTY and show them in a new column in python polars?

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a dataframe as-

```
pl.DataFrame({'last_name':['Unknown','Mallesham',np.nan,'Bhavik','Unknown'],
                  'first_name_or_initial':['U',np.nan,'TRUE','yamulla',np.nan],
                  'number':['003123490','012457847','100030303','','0023004648'],
                'date_of_birth':[np.nan,'12/09/1900','12/09/1900','12/09/1900',np.nan]})
```

[image]

Here I would like to add a new column which contains the field names that do hold on any information except NULL/EMPTY/NAN.

For example:

first row: it has last,first and number field information, and dob is NULL, hence a new column conso_field is filled in with these field names such as last_name,first_name_or_initial and number. like wise I need to get this done for all the rows.

Here is an expected output:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's expand the example to show a row with all null/empty fields (to show how the algorithm handles this case).

```py
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "last_name": ["Unknown", "Mallesham", np.nan, "Bhavik", "Unknown", None],
        "first_name_or_initial": ["U", np.nan, "TRUE", "yamulla", np.nan, None],
        "number": ["003123490", "012457847", "100030303", "", "0023004648", None],
        "date_of_birth": [np.nan, "12/09/1900", "12/09/1900", "12/09/1900", np.nan, None],
    }
)
df
```

```
shape: (6, 4)
┌───────────┬───────────────────────┬────────────┬───────────────┐
│ last_name ┆ first_name_or_initial ┆ number     ┆ date_of_birth │
│ ---       ┆ ---                   ┆ ---        ┆ ---           │
│ str       ┆ str                   ┆ str        ┆ str           │
╞═══════════╪═══════════════════════╪════════════╪═══════════════╡
│ Unknown   ┆ U                     ┆ 003123490  ┆ null          │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Mallesham ┆ null                  ┆ 012457847  ┆ 12/09/1900    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ null      ┆ TRUE                  ┆ 100030303  ┆ 12/09/1900    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Bhavik    ┆ yamulla               ┆            ┆ 12/09/1900    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Unknown   ┆ null                  ┆ 0023004648 ┆ null          │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ null      ┆ null                  ┆ null       ┆ null          │
└───────────┴───────────────────────┴────────────┴───────────────┘
```

##### The Algorithm

```py
df = df.with_row_count()

(
    df
    .join(
        df
        .melt(id_vars="row_nr")
        .filter(pl.col('value').is_not_null() & (pl.col('value') != ""))
        .groupby('row_nr')
        .agg(pl.col('variable').alias('conso_field'))
        .with_column(pl.col('conso_field').arr.join(','))
        ,
        on='row_nr',
        how='left'
    )
)
```

```
shape: (6, 6)
┌────────┬───────────┬───────────────────────┬────────────┬───────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────┐
│ row_nr ┆ last_name ┆ first_name_or_initial ┆ number     ┆ date_of_birth ┆ conso_field                         │
│ ---    ┆ ---       ┆ ---                   ┆ ---        ┆ ---           ┆ ---                                 │
│ u32    ┆ str       ┆ str                   ┆ str        ┆ str           ┆ str                                 │
╞════════╪═══════════╪═══════════════════════╪════════════╪═══════════════╪═════════════════════════════════════╡
│ 0      ┆ Unknown   ┆ U                     ┆ 003123490  ┆ null          ┆ last_name,first_name_or_initial,... │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1      ┆ Mallesham ┆ null                  ┆ 012457847  ┆ 12/09/1900    ┆ last_name,number,date_of_birth      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ null      ┆ TRUE                  ┆ 100030303  ┆ 12/09/1900    ┆ first_name_or_initial,number,dat... │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3      ┆ Bhavik    ┆ yamulla               ┆            ┆ 12/09/1900    ┆ last_name,first_name_or_initial,... │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4      ┆ Unknown   ┆ null                  ┆ 0023004648 ┆ null          ┆ last_name,number                    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5      ┆ null      ┆ null                  ┆ null       ┆ null          ┆ null                                │
└────────┴───────────┴───────────────────────┴────────────┴───────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Note that the algorithm keeps the last row with all null/empty values.

##### How it works

To see how it works, let's take it in steps.
First, we'll need to attach a row number to each row.  (This is needed in case any row has all null/empty values.)

Then we'll use [`melt`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.melt.html) to place each value in each column on a separate row, next to it's column name.

```py
df = df.with_row_count()
(
    df
    .melt(id_vars="row_nr")
)
```

```
shape: (24, 3)
┌────────┬───────────────┬────────────┐
│ row_nr ┆ variable      ┆ value      │
│ ---    ┆ ---           ┆ ---        │
│ u32    ┆ str           ┆ str        │
╞════════╪═══════════════╪════════════╡
│ 0      ┆ last_name     ┆ Unknown    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1      ┆ last_name     ┆ Mallesham  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ last_name     ┆ null       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3      ┆ last_name     ┆ Bhavik     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...    ┆ ...           ┆ ...        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ date_of_birth ┆ 12/09/1900 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3      ┆ date_of_birth ┆ 12/09/1900 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4      ┆ date_of_birth ┆ null       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5      ┆ date_of_birth ┆ null       │
└────────┴───────────────┴────────────┘
```

Note that columns values will be converted to string values in this step.

Next, we'll filter out any rows with `null` or "" values.

```py
df = df.with_row_count()
(
    df
    .melt(id_vars="row_nr")
    .filter(pl.col('value').is_not_null() & (pl.col('value') != ""))
)
```

```
shape: (14, 3)
┌────────┬───────────────┬────────────┐
│ row_nr ┆ variable      ┆ value      │
│ ---    ┆ ---           ┆ ---        │
│ u32    ┆ str           ┆ str        │
╞════════╪═══════════════╪════════════╡
│ 0      ┆ last_name     ┆ Unknown    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1      ┆ last_name     ┆ Mallesham  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3      ┆ last_name     ┆ Bhavik     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4      ┆ last_name     ┆ Unknown    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...    ┆ ...           ┆ ...        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4      ┆ number        ┆ 0023004648 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1      ┆ date_of_birth ┆ 12/09/1900 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ date_of_birth ┆ 12/09/1900 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3      ┆ date_of_birth ┆ 12/09/1900 │
└────────┴───────────────┴────────────┘
```

In the next step, we'll aggregate up all the remaining rows by row number, keeping only the column names.  These represent columns with non-null, non-empty values.

```py
df = df.with_row_count()
(
    df
    .melt(id_vars="row_nr")
    .filter(pl.col('value').is_not_null() & (pl.col('value') != ""))
    .groupby('row_nr')
    .agg(pl.col('variable').alias('conso_field'))
)
```

```
shape: (5, 2)
┌────────┬─────────────────────────────────────┐
│ row_nr ┆ conso_field                         │
│ ---    ┆ ---                                 │
│ u32    ┆ list[str]                           │
╞════════╪═════════════════════════════════════╡
│ 2      ┆ ["first_name_or_initial", "numbe... │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3      ┆ ["last_name", "first_name_or_ini... │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4      ┆ ["last_name", "number"]             │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0      ┆ ["last_name", "first_name_or_ini... │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1      ┆ ["last_name", "number", "date_of... │
└────────┴─────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Note that we get a list of column names for each row.  (Note: we don't need to worry about the order of the rows at this point.  We'll use the row number and a left-join in the last step recombine the values to the original DataFrame.)

Then, it's simply a matter of joining the columns names into one string:

```py
df = df.with_row_count()
(
    df
    .melt(id_vars="row_nr")
    .filter(pl.col('value').is_not_null() & (pl.col('value') != ""))
    .groupby('row_nr')
    .agg(pl.col('variable').alias('conso_field'))
    .with_column(pl.col('conso_field').arr.join(','))
)
```

```
shape: (5, 2)
┌────────┬─────────────────────────────────────┐
│ row_nr ┆ conso_field                         │
│ ---    ┆ ---                                 │
│ u32    ┆ str                                 │
╞════════╪═════════════════════════════════════╡
│ 3      ┆ last_name,first_name_or_initial,... │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ first_name_or_initial,number,dat... │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4      ┆ last_name,number                    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0      ┆ last_name,first_name_or_initial,... │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1      ┆ last_name,number,date_of_birth      │
└────────┴─────────────────────────────────────┘
```

From here, we simply use a "left join" to merge the data back to the original dataset (as shown at the beginning.)